# matplotlib's dateformatter treats seconds as days

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, python-datetime

When using `DateFormatter`, I expect it to convert ints to dates as unix timestamps. Meaning:

- 0 is 1970/01/01 00:00:00
- 1 is 1970/01/01 00:00:01

instead, I get that 1 ==> 1970/01/02 00:00:00

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter([0, 1], [1, 1])
xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

[image: output of the code]

Comment: The docstring for [`DateFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter) says: _"Format a tick (in **days** since the epoch) with a `strftime` format string."_ So your assumption it should count in seconds appears to be wrong.

Comment: damn it, didn't notice....
thanks!
also, is there a nicer solution then to divide it all by 24*3600?

Comment: I don't know of a better solution (but that doesn't mean there isn't one!)

Comment: perhaps convert your x values to a `datetime` object first?

Comment: that's another option yeah, but I have a lot of different objects on the same plot. never mind. thanks again.